# Where is and how to edit the default Django homepage

Tags: django

Created a test demo project as below, how to edit the default Django homepage (or create my own homepage) that still using the same homepage url http://127.0.0.1:8000/?

Note: I don't want to create a new app and put the homepage under the new app, because that could change the homepage url from http://127.0.0.1:8000/ to http://127.0.0.1:8000/new_app.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the default page back by adding the following in the urls.py file of your main app.

```
…
from django.views import debug
…

urlpatterns = [
    …
    path('', debug.default_urlconf),
    …
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You merely need to add the appropriate html template file and put the path into your project `urls.py` file. For example you could create a templates folder, under which you could add `base.html` or `home.html` or whatever you want (with the associated view), and then in `urls.py` you add:

```
path('', views.home),
```