# How is django's default root homepage rendered?

Tags: python, django, url, routes

This is a kind of want-to-know itch.  Many questions here ask how to replace the default Django homepage ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63239416/where-is-and-how-to-edit-the-default-django-homepage) ).  I understand that issue.  What I'm curious to know is how the default page is rendered when a new project is created (i.e., in debug mode).  Even though my question is not as directly practical as knowing how to replace the default homepage, I have the feeling that if I figure it out, I may understand how Django works a bit better.

I would expect it to be in the default urls.py file, but the only entry by default in `urlpatterns` of urls.py is `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)`.  My first naive expectation would be an entry in urlpatterns that you could remove or comment out.  Since there's nothing there besides `admin/`, I'm guessing there's some other built-in app or middleware that specifies the default homepage, but I don't know where to look.

Here's my progress in understanding this so far:

- Commenting out `DEBUG=True` in settings.py causes the default homepage to no longer appear.
- I've seen [this documentation about how Django processes requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request), which mentions middleware that can set the urlconf attribute on a request that changes the default, `ROOT_URLCONF`.

So far Django has been pretty straightforward, but this seems like something magical, so I'm trying to figure out what's going on behind the scenes.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8bcb00858e0ddec79cc96669c238d29c30d7effb/django/views/debug.py#L533). Django basically has a special case for when no matching URL is found in the URL configuration, and the requested path is `/`, and there is only one entry in the URL configuration.

In that case it loads a `default_urlconf` which [renders that welcome template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8bcb00858e0ddec79cc96669c238d29c30d7effb/django/views/debug.py#L575-L583) in place of a regular 404 response.

This is called from inside the `technical_404_response` function, which [is only called](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca9872905559026af82000e46cde6f7dedc897b6/django/core/handlers/exception.py#L56-L59) when `DEBUG=True`.